# Azure functions using java and Postgres DB bindings

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-functions

I have a java application hosted in azure which is connecting to azure managed PostgreSQL DB.
Currently i am exploring the possibilities of azure functions using java. I can see Cosmos DB triggers and bindings for azure functions. But i didn't find any reference to PostgreSQL DB triggers or bindings. I understand from the blogs that we can connect to PostgreSQL inside azure functions and perform the required operations.
But my doubt is if we can use PostgreSQL similar to cosmos DB with bindings and triggers.

Comment: The azure function's binding support is limited, please have a look of this offcial doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the binding support of azure function is limited, please refer to this document for details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings

Although the special DB you specify may not be supported by the function's binding, you can still install the relevant packages and write the connection and input and output code inside the function logic. This is essentially the same as binding.